# Storage space running out when using adoptable storage

Tags: internal-storage, storage, adoptable-storage

I'm using adoptable storage in Android 8.0.0. I have a persistent notification that says "Storage space running out. Some system functions may not work."

Settings > Storage shows this:

[image: 16.68 total used of 24.00, internal shared storage 15.75 used of 16.00, sd card 0.93 used of 8.00]

Attempting to move apps to the SD card from there results in a toast that says "Not enough storage space."

How can I make use of the whole 24.00 GB I get with the SD card?

Comment: I don't think you've formatted as portable storage, which is why adoptable storage isn't working.

Comment: You think that's bad?  I get the same notification, but my above screen says 32.55GB of 128GB used internally, 32GB of 32GB used on the USB drive, yet I didn't even copy anything to the USB drive, which in itself is only 16GB!!!